# Unresponsive app-release.apk

Tags: android, android-studio

i have generated an app-release.apk in my android studio,but when i install it on my phone it installs correctly but the app wont start but it worked the first time and now am stuck,i dont know am doin wrong..i really need it to work for my project,any help that will guide to solve the problem is highly appreciated,i realy need help to figure things out.
    Here is my manifest.`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2"android:required="true" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/appicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
         android:name=".NavigationDrawer"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
         </intent-filter>
     </activity>
     <!-- All Product Activity -->
          <activity  android:name=".SplashScreen">  </activity>
         <activity  android:name=".Login_Fragment">  </activity>
         <activity  android:name=".NewPlayer">  </activity>
         <activity  android:name=".SearchTeamPlayers"></activity>
         <activity  android:name=".SignUp_Fragment">  </activity>
         <activity  android:name=".ViewEmployee">  </activity>
         <activity  android:name=".ViewAllEmployee">  </activity>
        <activity  android:name=".Players_Gallery"> </activity>
         <activity  android:name=".About"> </activity>
        <activity  android:name=".Counties"> </activity>
        <activity  android:name=".Wards"> </activity>
         <activity  android:name=".Search_Main"> </activity>
         <activity  android:name=".Search_Players"> </activity>
         <activity  android:name=".Search_Teams"> </activity>
         <activity  android:name=".ShowSubCounties"> </activity>
         <activity  android:name=".ShowWards"> </activity>
         <activity  android:name=".ShowStadium"> </activity>
         <activity  android:name=".SubCounties"> </activity>
     </application>

 </manifest>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "the app wont start but it worked the first time and now am stuck" ?

Comment: i mean i generated the apk first time and it launched when i installed it on my android phone,but now it wont launch the application after installing on my phone..it just keeps crushing everytime after installation

Comment: And what does the crash message say ?

Comment: Av just installed it manually on my phone,there no message..it just installs successfully but wont open the application

Comment: Connect your phone to your computer, you can see the crash log in LogCat console

Comment: What is your Android version and what are your minSDK and targetSDK..?

Comment: It generates the apk successfully on my android studio,then i transfer to my phone manually and install it..it install successfully but wont start the application,it just crush..there's no error message shown

Comment: my minSDK is 4.4(KitKat) and the target version is 6.0(Marshmallow).